# How to add a margin to a specific <apex: selectOptions>

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I have a multiple-select picklist converted to checkboxes and I want to add add a margin to some of the checkboxes, since all the options came from a multiple-select picklist I don't know how to isolate specific selections. Thanks.

My VF Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="EthnicityPageIIController" lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Ethnicity" columns="1" collapsible="false">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pageDirection"  value="{!MSItems}" label="Ethnicity" onclick="rerender">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="panel" action="{!specifyOption}"/>
                    <apex:selectoptions value="{!getMSPicklist}"/>  
                </apex:selectcheckboxes>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
                    <apex:inputText value="{! ctc.Other_Origin__c}" label="Other Origin" rendered="{!TheHispanic.size!=0}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageblockSection>

        <apex:pageblockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveContact}"/>                
        </apex:pageblockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

My Apex Controller:

```
public class EthnicityPageIIController {

private final Contact ctc;

public EthnicityPageIIController() {

    ctc =[SELECT Id, Ethnicity__c, Hispanic_or_Latin_Origin__c, Other_Origin__c, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

}

public Contact getctc() {
    return ctc;
}    
public void saveContact() {
    upsert ctc;
}
public List<String> displaySelectedText {get;set;}


public List<SelectOption> getMsPicklist {
    get {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry obj : Contact.Ethnicity__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(obj.getValue(), obj.getLabel()));
        }
        return options;
    }
    set;
}



public String[] MSItems {
    get {
        List<String> selected = new List<String>();
        List<SelectOption> options = this.getMSPicklist;
        for(SelectOption obj : options) {
            if(this.ctc.Ethnicity__c != null && this.ctc.Ethnicity__c.contains(obj.getValue()))
                selected.add(obj.getValue());

        }
        System.debug('selected ' + selected);
        return selected;

    }public set {
        String selectedCheckBox = '';
        for(String s : value) {
            if (selectedCheckBox == '') 
                selectedCheckBox += s;
            else selectedCheckBox += ';' + s;            
        }
        ctc.Ethnicity__c = selectedCheckbox;
    }
}


public PageReference specifyOption() {
    displaySelectedText = MSItems;
    System.debug(displaySelectedText);
    return null;

}


public List<String> TheHispanic {
    get {
        List<String> hispanics = new List<String>();
        for(String val : MSItems) {
            if(val.contains('Other')) 
                hispanics.add(val);

        }

    System.debug('this is the size ' + hispanics.size());
    return hispanics;

    }set;

  }
```

}

How it looks now:
[image]

How I want the page to look:

[image]

Comment: just a thought: can't you turn `MSItems` into a `Map<String, List<String>>` and then use that to add indentation where necessary?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely do that, but how do I add styling to the result of the map? Tried using apex:repeat but didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using nested ordere/unordered lists. As you are using `apex:pageblockSection` and `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`, using nested lists won't work as well.

So I removed both and added standard HTML tag `ul` and `li` with some CSS to hide the bullet points.

Here is the sample code.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <style>
        li {
            list-style: none
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >


            <ul>
                <li>
                    <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pageDirection" label="Ethnicity1" onclick="rerender">    
                   <apex:selectOption itemValue="Ethnicity1" itemLabel="Ethnicity1"/>
                    </apex:selectcheckboxes>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pageDirection"  label="a" onclick="rerender"> 
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="a" itemLabel="a"/>

                            </apex:selectcheckboxes>
                        </li>

                        <li><apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pageDirection"  label="b" onclick="rerender">
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="b" itemLabel="b"/>

                            </apex:selectcheckboxes>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pageDirection"  label="Ethnicity2" onclick="rerender">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Ethnicity2" itemLabel="Ethnicity2"/>
                    </apex:selectcheckboxes>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <apex:pageblockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save"/>                
            </apex:pageblockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the output in LEX.

[image]

Here is the output in Salesforce Classic 
 [image]

> Please note that you can use `selectOptions` instead of `selectOption` if needed.